# How to manage inadvertent shake events on iphone

Tags: iphone, event-handling

I started experimenting with a shake event handler to erase some data in my app. My shake handler starts by intercepting the shake event inside a subclassed UIApplication.

I found that if I put the phone in my pocket with the app running, it gets shaken and initiates the erase operation.  I use a modal alert to wait for user confirmation, but it seems undesirable to always see this alert when removing it from my pocket.

Can someone offer an idea on how to automatically disable this when it occurs in the pocket?

One idea I have is to use a timeout. If the alert is ignored for a certain amount of time, then the shake is ignored. I'm wondering if there are any other solutions.

Comment: Did you manage to overcome your issue yet?

Comment: Not yet. It's a post release update, so it's not a burning priority. Still considering it. I'll follow up here, though. I might validate on the device having been face up immediately before the shake gesture.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ambient light/proximity sensor. Poll it to see if it detects light, if it does initiate the erase, if not don't. That would take care of the 'in the pocket' issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for multiple shake gestures to have occurred.  If you don't get a second (or third or nth) gesture within a timeout, then ignore the gesture? Most deliberate shakes would cause multiple gestures.

Comment: Your suggestion looks like a good place to start. From what I have seen, shaking can lead to several shake events. this is going to require som emore tests. the shake-to-erase may not be to helpful in the end, but caught interest because it's like using an etech-a-sketch behavior.